# Synapse Pipeline Cost - Cost Management Download

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-synapse, cost-management

In the Cost Analysis download file, how do I get the cost for a specific pipeline run?  On the Monitor page, the pipeline run has a Run ID.  The Run ID is in found in the downloaded file.    How can I get the cost?

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately - it is not possible to get cost per pipeline in Azure Data Factory from cost analaysis page.

Appreciate if you could share the feedback on our [feedback channel](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/search/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c?q=cost%20per%20pipeline). Which would be open for the user community to upvote & comment on. This allows our product teams to effectively prioritize your request against our existing feature backlog and gives insight into the potential impact of implementing the suggested feature.

> As per the repro from my end - when I download the cost analysis - it does not contains any pipeline runs IDS - it just shows the cost occurred per day.

[image]

**Note:** The data shown in the summary page contains your subscription ID and not the ADF pipeline ID.

[image]

**Note:** The Data page contains the cost occurred per day and the forecast cost for the ADF resources.

[image]

**Note:** You can [Monitor consumption at pipeline-run level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/plan-manage-costs#monitor-consumption-at-pipeline-run-level) - Depending on the types of activities you have in your pipeline, how much data you are moving and transforming, and the complexity of the transformation, executing a pipeline will spin different billing meters in Azure Data Factory.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this information.    How can I submit a MSFT request  to provide cost by Synapse pipeline in Cost Management?  When using Databricks, Cost Management has Jobs cost information.

Comment: You can leave your feedback on the ADF feedback forum or upvote the existing item: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/search/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c?q=cost%20per%20pipeline